# How I can use a ListView with a default row and can add new rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, active-directory, listviewitem

I want to use a ListView for my ASP.NET Application and I want if I start the application I the the ListView with one Row and this Row have a few columns with TextBoxes. The Application is for create a device in the active directory and if the user put the data in the first row for a device and the user have a other device, he can click on a symbol to create a second row for the second device. If he click than on the save button the application create entrys in active directory for the two devices.

My Question is now how I can use a Listview with a default row and create a new row if i click on a button. can everyone help me or show me good sites.

[image]

Comment: Take a DataTable, add a empty row to it and assign that DataTable as DataSource for the ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET-3-5).

Basically, what you will have to do is having your "empty" `ListView` containing one line with the text input boxes and once the user clicks the "Add" button, you insert a row above that line and clear all input boxes.

BTW, the article show you also how you can edit and delete existing items of the list.